# File not found error in Mysql and how can i load the txt file in to table

Tags: mysql

I write a query to insert file data  to a table as follows

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Merge.txt' 
INTO TABLE tblachmaster
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But this is giving me an error as

```
C:Documents and SettingsAdministratorDesktopMerge.txt not found can any one tell why
```

My data in file is as follows i would like to insert using the query

```
101 111100022 5104885671104200936A094101CapitalOne                           MudiamInc        
5220MudiamInc                           A510488567CCDITServices000000110422   1111100020000001
622968765348545646565        00004000001007           rajeshk                 1111100020000001
62297877654775676546546      00002888891007           rajeshk                 1111100020000002
82200000020194754188000000000000000000688889A510488567                         111100020000001
5220MudiamInc                           A510488567CCDITServices000000110422   1111100020000002
62212345678034354465677      00000864451005           swethau                 1111100020000003
62212345678087664534543      00000559841011           swathiK                 1111100020000004
62212345678097867546435      00000579351012           lavanyaK                1111100020000005
6221234567806754654435435    00000846761013           AnithaN                 1111100020000006
82200000040049382712000000000000000000285040A510488567                         111100020000002
9000002000001000000060244136900000000000000000071739300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be wrong slashes: `\` instead of `/`? Note: `\` often means escaping, like in `\n`.

Comment: Ok, but you certainly should use these ones. I understand the file itself exists? You could also try `\\ ` instead of `\ `.

Answer (score 2):

If you use backslashes `\` you probably need double backslashes: `\\`.  Otherwise, you can replace them with slashes instead `/`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Merge.txt'
```